# Cannot create folders and files anywhere but my /home directory

Tags: debian, fstab, automounting, kde5

I use Debian Testing with KDE 5.
I cannot create files or folders except my `/home/semko` dir.
(User ´semko´ is I -the sole user of my PC. And I would like to have access to all my drives)

On `/home/semko` dir, when I right click and see the following properties:

[image]

However on my other drives I see this:

[image]

I though this was something to do with `fstab`. So I changed my default fstab (generated by Debian installation) from this:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=e65325bf-88c0-4b4b-9aa2-aea07ef659de /       ext4   
errors=remount-ro 0   1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=B8F3-B50F  /boot/efi   vfat    umask=0077  0   1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=22bd59d4-b4c9-4509-b6dc-00faf700f23c none        swap    sw       
      0       0
```

to that:

```
 cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=e65325bf-88c0-4b4b-9aa2-aea07ef659de /               ext4   noatime,defaults,discard  0    0
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=B8F3-B50F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=22bd59d4-b4c9-4509-b6dc-00faf700f23c none            swap    sw              0       0
# mount wdP1
UUID=2bf4cc1c-7e84-4e34-adb9-0d2fbf5ed1a7 /media/mnt/wdP1mnt ext4 noatime,defaults,discard  0    0
# mount hitaP1
UUID=70686D3664DCF58D /media/mnt/hitaP1mnt ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0002,fmask=0003 0 0
# mount wdP2
UUID=127724642DFFF971 /media/mnt/wdP2mnt ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0002,fmask=0003 0 0
# mount win10
UUID=FC9816989816518E /media/mnt/win10mnt ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0002,fmask=0003 0 0
```

These are my drives (`sda` is an **SSD**, `sdb` and `sdc` are HDDs):

```
$ lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL    UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                         
├─sda1 ntfs   Recovery FC42F32142F2DF78                     
├─sda2 vfat            B8F3-B50F                            /boot/efi
├─sda3                                                      
├─sda4 ntfs            FC9816989816518E                     /media/mnt/win10mnt
├─sda5 swap            22bd59d4-b4c9-4509-b6dc-00faf700f23c [SWAP]
└─sda6 ext4   debDwell e65325bf-88c0-4b4b-9aa2-aea07ef659de /
sdb                                                         
├─sdb1 vfat   EFIWD    4C26-549A                            
├─sdb2 ext4   wdP1     2bf4cc1c-7e84-4e34-adb9-0d2fbf5ed1a7 /media/mnt/wdP1mnt
└─sdb3 ntfs   wdP2     127724642DFFF971                     /media/mnt/wdP2mnt
sdc                                                         
├─sdc1 vfat   EFI      F392-8011                            
└─sdc2 ntfs   hitaP1   70686D3664DCF58D                     /media/mnt/hitaP1mnt
```

Comment: Actually, what you are calling `/home` is likely `/home/semko`. You also should add the contents of `/etc/fstab` to the question.

Comment: actually had given paste.debian links to both my `fstab` files (bolded them to make more visible)

Comment: Not sure why you just didn't make the fstab files part of the question like the output for `lsblk -f`.

Comment: @Deathgrip didn't want to make the question even longer. ok, i am pasting them here anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Simple Linux permissions. The user `semko` owns its `$HOME` directory. Most other directories on a Linux system are owned by `root` or some other system related account and are writeable only by `root` or those accounts.

Probably what you want is:

```
# chgrp semko /media/mnt/*
# chmod g+w /media/mnt/*
```

Personal preference for me to use group ownership rather than user ownership for this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62610/discussion-between-deathgrip-and-saloma).